# How to create a local CRAN repository for an older version of R

Tags: r, cran

I work for a government agency that is very skeptical of open source software.  They have only recently allowed us to install R and R-Studio at all.  Even then, we are limited to R version 3.x and only on machines that are NOT connected to a network.  So at best I can install R 3.6.3, and since I won't be connected to the internet I won't be able to connect to a CRAN mirror to install packages.  Is there a guide someplace that outlines how I can deploy a local package repository for

- an older version of R
- a complete mirror of the packages on CRAN

I have found some guides on setting up mini repositories of selected packages, but am unclear on how to get the older versions of packages that are sure to compatible with 3.6.3.  And I realize a complete mirror is probably excessive, but I expect this setup to be used by a number of people in my office and I can't really predict what packages they will need.  I don't think waiting until they need something and then trying to get it downloaded and added will be a timely solution...and I don't want this to become my full-time job either.

This will be on a Windows machine.

Comment: This isn't really a thing that's easily supported. You can use a site like the RStudio Package Manager https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/ to get snapshots of CRAN from the past. you could choose a date what would be consistent with R 3.6.3. But you still have to manually setup your own repo with those packages. [minicran](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-introduction.html) can help with that. But if you want people to install ad-hoc packages that's going to be tricky.

Comment: Check out the Microsoft time machine: https://mran.microsoft.com/timemachine

Comment: Seems like sorting out a good workflow with `minicran` will be your best bet. I feel like if you had a good workflow to identify package needed, download them from CRAN, and transfer them to the internal machines, then adding packages on request might not be *too* hard.  The trickiest bit would be identifying appropriate older versions of the packages known to be OK with 3.6.x.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck:  Microsoft is shutting down their `mran` web site in a few months.  See the notice at the top of their main page.  So a copy should be made soon!